# Tools or Techniques for Removing Grass and Moss from Brick Patio

Tags: patio, weeds

This is what I'm dealing with - rudimentary efforts have not paid off and I feel like I must be missing something.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried plain old bleach and water? I find it kills just about everything, and is great in general. I would bet muriatic acid would be similarly effective, just by nature of its strength

Comment: I would be interested in eco-friendly approaches.

Comment: @BrownRedHawk bleach will kill the top of the plant, the root will live tho and grow back. If I wasn't using roundup for this job I'd chose salt and ammonia which will kill the root, roundup is still better for this tho but pricier.

Answer (score 2):

Round-Up 365 will stop frequent reoccurrence. But, with Round-Up 365 only, you spray everything down & when dead & dry in 2-weeks, just scuff the remnants away with your shoe or a string trimmer.

Birds & wind are your enemies & the only way to avoid this entirely is to go with slab concrete. Not a good option unless it's colored concrete, your pavers look worlds better. You'll need to repeat the Round-Up 365 & shoe or string trimmer annually or bi-annually.

Filling the paver joints won't do anything good. It would ruin drainage, looks & the pavers much needed movements.

Comment: +1 We used to have a patio just like this. Roundup all the way.

Comment: Thank you!  That's really helpful.  One question about Round Up.  There are occasionally bunnies that come by and nibble on these weeds and grass.  Will that product poison them?  (It might be okay if I physically pull out the tallest ones, those seem like the main ones the bunnies are drawn to)

Comment: No problem, they sniff out what's healthy or not first. But, you can trim them down with a mower at its lowest setting or a string trimmer, animals usually just eat the new growth tips. Also the paver joints are just filled with regular sand, so anything you pull out you can just broom sand back in or over the whole patio to fill-in back to the top.